# Dibujar figura con css

Tags: css, css3

Necesito dibujar esta figura con css

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como podría hacerlo??

Tengo esto pero no logro hacerlo.

Código css:

```
.seccion
{
    width: 350px;
    height: 200px;
    border-left: 70px solid #fff;
    border-right: 70px solid #fff;
    border-top: 100px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 50% 50% 0 0;
}
```

Código html:

```
<div class="seccion">
</div>
```

Yo necesito formar esto, solo el contorno de cada figura.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Qué has intentado hasta ahora? [Edita tu pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/220491/edit) agregando tu progreso

Comment: Hola @Jorge Alonso, ten en cuenta como puedes preguntar para que podamos ayudarte, ademas de adjuntar codigo lo que tienes, tus he intentos, no pretendas que hagamos todo tu trabajo.

Comment: No tengo nada de codigo por que no se me ocurre nada :(

Comment: Yo lo haría con SVG. Por cierto: aquellas cositas pequeñas son números?

Comment: Si pero solo importa la figura

Comment: ¿Solo necesitas la parte verde entonces?

Answer (score 2):

Si necesitas solo el svg lo puedes copiar del inspector. Espero que esto sea lo que necesites.

```js
var SVG_NS = 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg';
var SVG_XLINK = "http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
var svg = document.querySelector("svg");
let c={x:700,y:700}
let a1 = -Math.PI/2 -Math.PI/4; 
let a2 = -Math.PI/2 - Math.PI/10;

for(let r = 300; r < 700; r+=10){
  let x1 = c.x + r*Math.cos(a1);
  let y1 = c.y + r*Math.sin(a1);
  let x2 = c.x + r*Math.cos(a2);
  let y2 = c.y + r*Math.sin(a2);
  let o = {
    d:`M${x1},${y1}A${r},${r} 0 0 1 ${x2},${y2}`
  }
  drawPath(o, svg)
}


function drawPath(o, parent) {
  var path = document.createElementNS(SVG_NS, 'path');
  for (var name in o) {
    if (o.hasOwnProperty(name)) {
      path.setAttributeNS(null, name, o[name]);
    }
  }
  parent.appendChild(path);
  return path;
}
```

```css
svg{border:1px solid;height:90vh;}
path{fill:none; stroke:black;}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="100 0 600 600"></svg>
```

#### Actualización:

El OP comenta: "Hubiera estado perfecto si dibujara el contorno y no las lineas". A continuación viene el código para dibujar solo el contorno.

```js
var SVG_NS = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";
var SVG_XLINK = "http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink";
var svg = document.querySelector("svg");
let c = { x: 700, y: 700 };
let a1 = -Math.PI / 2 - Math.PI / 4;
let a2 = -Math.PI / 2 - Math.PI / 10;

// dibujar contorno

let x1 = c.x + 300 * Math.cos(a1);
let y1 = c.y + 300 * Math.sin(a1);
let x2 = c.x + 300 * Math.cos(a2);
let y2 = c.y + 300 * Math.sin(a2);

let x3 = c.x + 690 * Math.cos(a2);
let y3 = c.y + 690 * Math.sin(a2);
let x4 = c.x + 690 * Math.cos(a1);
let y4 = c.y + 690 * Math.sin(a1);

let o = {
  style: "fill:hsla(110, 70% ,40%,.35)",
  d: `M${x1},${y1}A${300},${300} 0 0 1 ${x2},${y2}L${x3},${y3}A${690},${690} 0 0 0 ${x4},${y4}L${x1},${y1}z`
};
drawPath(o, svg);

function drawPath(o, parent) {
  var path = document.createElementNS(SVG_NS, "path");
  for (var name in o) {
    if (o.hasOwnProperty(name)) {
      path.setAttributeNS(null, name, o[name]);
    }
  }
  parent.appendChild(path);
  return path;
}
```

```css
svg{border:1px solid;width:90vh;}
path{fill:none; stroke:black;}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="100 0 600 600"></svg>
```

Comment: Hubiera estado perfecto si dibujara el contorno y no las lineas.

Comment: Te agradezco mucho que me estés ayudando pero la verdad no entiendo como funciona tu código, svg nunca lo habia escuchado ni visto y la verdad no tengo idea de como trabaja, aparte de esta figura necesito dibujar más figuras y le intente mover a tu codigo pero no tuve éxito :(

Comment: El escenario que pongo es lo que necesito formar pero solamente había puesto la primer figura para ver si podía basarme de ella para hacer las demas pero veo que no estoy teniendo éxito.

Comment: @JorgeAlonso gracias por comentar. He añadido otra respuesta donde utilizo solo CSS. Por lastima estoy utilizando `clip-path` que no funciona en Edge y IE. Si en un futuro decides estudiar SVG esta es una buena introducción en castellano: [SVG - una introducción](http://w3.unpocodetodo.info/svg/introduccion.php)

Answer (score 1):

Esto se acerca a lo que buscas, podrías ir variando este código hasta que se adapte mejor a tus necesidades:

```css
#figura {
         border-bottom: 200px solid #9dce98;
        border-left: 25px solid transparent;
        border-right: 25px solid transparent;
        height: 0;
        width: 100px;
        transform: rotate(140deg);
        margin-top: 100px;
        margin-left: 50px;
     }
```

```html
<div id="figura"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Esta es otra respuesta porque el OP dice no saber trabajar con SVG así que a continuación viene un intento de hacerlo con CSS:

**Explicación:**

1. En el HTML tengo un div que a la parte superior tiene los bordes redondeados.
2. Este div tiene `overflow:hidden`.
3. También tiene un pseudo elemento `before` con la parte superior redondeada. Este elemento es transparente pero tiene una sombra que llena el div.
4. A continuación utilizo `clip-path` para cortarlo todo en forma trapezoidal, y finalmente
5. Lo giro con `transform:rotate`.

```css
div{
  width:150px;
  height:200px;
  overflow:hidden;
  position:absolute;
  margin:auto;
  left:0;right:0;top:0;bottom:0;
  border-top-left-radius:  50%  5% ;
  border-top-right-radius: 50%  5%;
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 75% 100%, 25% 100% );
  transform:rotate(-15deg);
}

div:before{
  content:"";
  display:block;
  width:100%;
  height:20px;
  border-top-left-radius:     50% ;
  border-top-right-radius:    50%;
  position:absolute;
  bottom:-10px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 300px hsla(120,70%,40%,.5);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

A diferencia de SVG esto funciona en Chrome y Firefox pero no en Edge, IE ya que estoy utilizando [clip-path](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-clip-path). En Safari funciona con prefijo.

Comment: Y si quisiera hacerlo mas ancho, así como esta la figura rosa (B)?? Le movi al width y los valores de polygon y no logré tener éxito??

Comment: Para hacer algo tan complejo te recomiendo SVG porque necesitas calcular coordenadas.